# Interacting with realm database on background thread

Tags: ios, realm, avplayer

I believe I should be able to work with a realm database on a background thread in an `iOS` app as long as I don't pass `realm objects` around that was created on another `thread`.  That being said, I am experiencing the following error:

> 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'

The code where I'm trying to do my realm operation is in an observer off of the `AVPlayer`. I have the observer setup to run on a background queue as shown below:

```
backgroundStateObserver = self.player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)) { (CMTime) -> Void in

    if self.player.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
       let realm = try! Realm()
       let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "episode_id = %@ AND user_id = %@", self.currentEpisode!.id, userId)
       var episode = realm.objects(ListenedToEpisode.self).filter(predicate).first

       ...
    }
```

The error is raised right after the "let realm" statement.  Is what I am trying to do not allowed?  If I put it inside a `Dispatch.main.async` statement, it works, but that seems like I shouldn't need to do that unless I'm misunderstanding what `realm` requires. Please help set me straight.

Comment: Put the line that causes error in the question. Does it contain reference to `Realm.Object`?

Comment: I edited my post to show some of the realm specific code. Interestingly enough, it fails on the line where the predicate is set, it doesn't appear to get to the next line where realm.objects is referenced.

Comment: `self.currentEpisode` — belongs to the Realm in the other thread. Move it using `ThreadSafeReference`

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense now that you pointed it out.  If you answer the question I will give you the credit for your help.  Thanks!